# Importar csv - 18 milhoes linhas no R

Tags: r, csv, importação

Como importar uma base de 20 milhoes de linhas com 24 variáveis. Há duas variáveis que são string. A base está importando essas duas variaveis como numeric e excluindo os zeros no início. Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
base <-read.csv("base.csv",header = TRUE,   sep=";", dec="." , quote = "", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAs = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse é um trabalho para o [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html)!

Com o readr você consegue ler a linhas e ele detecta automaticamente o tipo das variáveis. Veja um exemplo:

```
library(readr)
sc <- read_csv2(file = '/media/backup/Microdados/sc2017.csv')
nrow(sc)
```

esse arquivo é o arquivo da RAIS relativo a todo o estado de Santa Catarina. Ele se encontra no formato CSV e está disponível [aqui](ftp://ftp.mtps.gov.br/pdet/microdados/RAIS/2017/SC2017.7z).

Além de tudo o `readr` é muito mais rápido e mais eficiente.

Só para você ver como fica no final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada! Essa função deu certo e no final  ele mostrou quais linhas estão com problemas.  Descobrir um string que começava com "" e acabou toda a linha a partir desse nome em uma única variável. Essa função  read_csv2 está junto com o comando 'Import Dataset' no Environment do RStudio. Clicando lá ele faz uma prévia das 200 primeiras linhas e vc consegue modificar qual tipo de variável que vc quer. Bem prático!

Comment: @NataliaSoares caso tenha escolhido essa resposta dé o tick para escolher e fechar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o argumento `colClasses` da função `read.csv`, onde se anunciará a classe de cada coluna. 
Exemplo:

`colClasses = c("character", "character", "complex", "factor", "factor", "character", "integer", "integer", "numeric", "character", "character", "Date", "integer", "logical")`

Minha sugestão é anunciar `colClasses = rep("character", 24)` e depois ir mudando a classe de cada coluna.

Comment: Obrigada Marcio! Anoite essa função rep("character", 24)